# firing href link for download and .click event with $.post() with jquery

Tags: ajax, forms, jquery, http-post

im trying to have one link for a file download and at the same time submit a post form over ajax.
kinda looks like this:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="form">
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="subscriber" id="subscriber" value="newsletter" />
    <a href="/files/application.exe" id="download">trial download</a>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // prevent default submit action caused by enter key etc.
    $("#form").bind('submit',function(event){event.preventDefault();});
    $('#download').click(function(){
        $.post(location.href, $('#form').serialize(), function(){
             $('#form').hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

problem is that the download fires and it shows the download dialog - which is correct - it also fires the click event and would even console log inside the click event function, it on top even fires the post request but the post request never ends up at the server. i had the access log file on tail -f and it only shows the GET on the application.exe but no POST from the $.post(). in firebug it shows the POST http://ip/folder/ given by the location.href and its marked in red with a little X and an empty response field. tough for firebug it looks like it got sent to the server...

my explanation for this is that the href takes the wind out of the $.post() and before it gets fired it redirects the browser to the download file. doesnt change the page itself but stops the action of posting over XHR...

does anyone know a good workaround for this? i really need the native href link to the application to not cause IE to bring up this stupid file download warning bar and at the same time i need the ajax to submit the form...

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refactor as follows, returning `false` to prevent the default link click behavior:

```
$('#download').click(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $.post(location.href, $('#form').serialize(), function(){
         $('#form').hide();
         document.location.href= href;
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: that for some reason works on the post side but doesnt fire the success function... hmm.

Comment: yeah, for some reason the success callback doesnt get fired. the server returns die( '{success:1}' ); right now whatever comes in over ajax... i see the response in firebug but success callback is not called at all... weird.

Comment: i removed header( 'Content-Type: application/json' ); from the response and now its firing the success callback... w.t.f.

Comment: any idea why this will not work with data in IE? ... i turned it into a .ajax call and it returns unknown error and doesnt even bother to send a request as soon as a data variable is given IE fires the error callback. when i remove the data value it works... wtf...

Answer (score 0):

to give one answer that works to my own question:

```
$('#download').click(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.post(location.href, $('#form').serialize(), function(){
             $('#form').hide();
        });
    },1000);
});
```

the timeout fires the .post after the download request is fired... sortof works... but i dont know if thats a good solution or if that might fail 50% of the time & browser...